# SQL: Fill missings in a ordered string sequence with dummies

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, replace

I have strings with sequences. The ideal string is **01-02-03-04** but in some records I have missings:

```
---------
| seq0  |
| ----- |
| 01-04 |
| 02-03 |
| 02-04 |
| 01-04 |
| 02    |
---------
```

These are examples. Any combination is possible. To recognize better what is missing I would like to insert **xx** for the missings to get this:

```
-----------------------
| seq0  | seq1        | 
| ----- | ----------- | 
| 01-04 | 01-xx-xx-04 | 
| 02-03 | xx-02-03-xx | 
| 02-04 | xx-02-xx-04 | 
| 01-04 | 01-xx-xx-04 | 
| 02    | xx-02-xx-xx | 
-----------------------
```

I have a solution using REGEXP and REPLACE (see below). But if the sequence ist longer (e.g.:01-...-12), it will be cumbersome to write the code. I wonder if there is a another way to do this. I could use short procedure (MySQL) but maybe there is an elegant way to do this with (nearly) pure SQL.

Code to produce the tables:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t0;
CREATE TABLE t0 (
  seq0       VARCHAR(100)
, seq1      VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO t0 (seq0) VALUES 
 ('01-04')
,('02-03')
,('02-04') 
,('01-04')
,('02')
;

SELECT * FROM t0;

UPDATE t0
SET seq1 = seq0
    -- insert xx       
    , seq1 = CASE WHEN seq1 REGEXP '01-03' THEN REPLACE(seq1,'01-03','01-xx-03') ELSE seq1 END
    , seq1 = CASE WHEN seq1 REGEXP '01-04' THEN REPLACE(seq1,'01-04','01-xx-xx-04') ELSE seq1 END   

    , seq1 = CASE WHEN seq1 REGEXP '02-04' THEN REPLACE(seq1,'02-04','02-xx-04') ELSE seq1 END   

    -- right pad xx
    , seq1 = CASE WHEN seq1 REGEXP '01$' THEN REPLACE(seq1,'01','01-xx-xx-xx') ELSE seq1 END   
    , seq1 = CASE WHEN seq1 REGEXP '02$' THEN REPLACE(seq1,'02','02-xx-xx') ELSE seq1 END   
    , seq1 = CASE WHEN seq1 REGEXP '03$' THEN REPLACE(seq1,'03','03-xx') ELSE seq1 END   

    -- left pad xx
    , seq1 = CASE WHEN seq1 REGEXP '^02' THEN REPLACE(seq1,'02','xx-02') ELSE seq1 END   
    , seq1 = CASE WHEN seq1 REGEXP '^03' THEN REPLACE(seq1,'03','xx-xx-03') ELSE seq1 END   
    , seq1 = CASE WHEN seq1 REGEXP '^04' THEN REPLACE(seq1,'04','xx-xx-xx-04') ELSE seq1 END   
    ;
SELECT * FROM t0;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use `REPLACE`:

```
SELECT seq0,
      REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
      REPLACE('01-02-03-04',
         CASE WHEN INSTR(seq0, '01') > 0 THEN 'u' ELSE '01' END, 'xx')
        ,CASE WHEN INSTR(seq0, '02') > 0 THEN 'u' ELSE '02' END, 'xx')
        ,CASE WHEN INSTR(seq0, '03') > 0 THEN 'u' ELSE '03' END, 'xx')
        ,CASE WHEN INSTR(seq0, '04') > 0 THEN 'u' ELSE '04' END, 'xx') AS result
FROM t0;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=308b8b2f40bfa5e26e49825a266ef9dd)**

Output:

```
┌───────┬─────────────┐
│ seq0  │   result    │
├───────┼─────────────┤
│ 01-04 │ 01-xx-xx-04 │
│ 02-03 │ xx-02-03-xx │
│ 02-04 │ xx-02-xx-04 │
│ 01-04 │ 01-xx-xx-04 │
│ 02    │ xx-02-xx-xx │
└───────┴─────────────┘
```

## EDIT

More advanced form(if you don't like nesting multiple replace):

```
SELECT seq0, result
FROM (
    SELECT seq0
        ,@u:= REPLACE(IF(@prev_value=seq0, @u,@start_string),
                      IF(INSTR(seq0, sub.c) > 0, 'u', sub.c), 'xx') AS result
        ,@cnt:=IF(@prev_value=seq0,@cnt-1,@l) AS c
        ,@prev_value := seq0
    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT *
        FROM t0 ,(SELECT '01' AS c UNION SELECT '02' 
                  UNION SELECT '03' UNION SELECT '04') num)sub
    ,(SELECT @u := ''
        ,@prev_value := ''
        ,@start_string := '01-02-03-04'
        ,@l := length(@start_string)-length(replace(@start_string,'-',''))
        ,@cnt := 0
        ) z
    ORDER BY sub.seq0, sub.c
) q
WHERE q.c = 0;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dbc239a925684078fbea1c66e6ed4b81)**

Output:

```
┌───────┬─────────────┐
│ seq0  │   result    │
├───────┼─────────────┤
│ 01-04 │ 01-xx-xx-04 │
│ 02    │ xx-02-xx-xx │
│ 02-03 │ xx-02-03-xx │
│ 02-04 │ xx-02-xx-04 │
└───────┴─────────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks for these solutions. The first one is easier to understand, the second I have to delve into. it will increase my knowledge in SQL as soon I grasp it.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use regular expressions.  It would be much faster using C# or another programming language but this should work.

Note: This does not handle seq0 having bad data.

```
ALTER FUNCTION F_GetPattern
(
    @Sequence VARCHAR(100)
)
RETURNS
VARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @T1 VARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @T2 VARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @I1 INT 
    DECLARE @I2 INT = 0
    DECLARE @Size INT = 4
    DECLARE @Index INT = 0
    DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(100) = ''

    SET @T1 = SUBSTRING(@Sequence, 1, 2)
    SET @T2 = SUBSTRING(@Sequence, 4, 2)

    SET @I1 = CAST(@T1 AS INT)
    IF (LEN(@Sequence ) > 3)
        SET @I2 = CAST(@T2 AS INT)

    WHILE @Index < @Size
    BEGIN
        IF @Index > 0 AND @Index < @Size
            SET @Result = @Result + '-'
        IF @Index + 1 = @I1 
            SET @Result = @Result + @T1
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            IF @Index + 1 = @I2
                SET @Result = @Result + @T2
            ELSE
                SET @Result = @Result + 'xx'
        END
        SET @Index = @Index + 1
    END

    return @Result
END
GO
SELECT seq0, DBO.F_GetPattern(seq0) FROM t0
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

While my answer above is good @Lukasz Szozda has a much simpler approach.  If you have just a few entries do yourself a favor and keep it simple like this!

If you need a more robust option that can be scaled to larger sequences then here is another option that uses STUFF(...).  It will most likely be more efficient than the other options if you have the sequence get big and you have to do this for a large number of records.

```
CREATE FUNCTION F_GetPattern
(
    @Sequence VARCHAR(100)
)
RETURNS
VARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @T1 VARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @T2 VARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @I1 INT 
    DECLARE @I2 INT = 0
    DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(100) = 'xx-xx-xx-xx'

    SET @T1 = SUBSTRING(@Sequence, 1, 2)
    SET @T2 = SUBSTRING(@Sequence, 4, 2)

    SET @I1 = CAST(@T1 AS INT)
    IF (LEN(@Sequence ) > 3)
        SET @I2 = CAST(@T2 AS INT)

    SET @Result = STUFF(@Result, @I1 * 3 -2, 2, @T1) 
    IF @I2 > 0
        SET @Result = STUFF(@Result, @I2 * 3 -2, 2, @T2)
    return @Result
END
GO
SELECT seq0, DBO.F_GetPattern(seq0) FROM t0
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for both solution. i'm not used in short procedure but I will try to understand it. Unfortunately, MariaDB has no STUFF function. I will try to find a workaround.

Comment: Which syntax is this?

Comment: That is SQL Server however you should be able to use "INSERT" for MySQL.  https://www.dbload.com/articles/mssql-stuff-function-in-mysql.htm